# Quantum algorithm for systems of linear equations with exponentially improved dependence on precision

Tags: hhl-algorithm

For [Quantum algorithm for systems of linear equations with exponentially improved dependence on precision](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02306), any idea why "we need oracle access to the nonzero entries of the rows and columns of A when A is not Hermitian" ?

Note: Non-hermitian properties does not 100% guarantee that the nonzero entries are located off-diagonal

[image: nonzero_entry_finding]

Answer (score 1):

Even if we know they are located off-diagonal, You need to know where exactly they are located. That's what the oracle guarantees.

edit since I cant edit the comment any more:

Ah, that makes more sense:) In the footnote, they mention:
when A is not hermitian but invertible, You can change it to a matrix
$B:=\begin{pmatrix}0&A\\A^{\dagger}&0
\end{pmatrix}$, which will be Hermitian again. Now, the matrix $A^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. Ergo, to have oracle access to row-entries of $B$, You can use the old oracle for  $A$ for the top half of the entries. However, the bottom half entries are the entries of the transpose of matrix $A$ (and also conjugate, this can be "easily" solved). Then, to get the rows of $A^{\dagger}$, you need the columns of $A$. So you need rows and columns of $A$ to get rows of $B$

Comment: wait, I just realized that my original question was wrong.  It should be "Why we need oracle access to the nonzero entries of the rows and columns of A when A is not Hermitian" ?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense:) In the footnote, they mention:
when A is not hermitian but invertible, You can change it to a matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}0&A\\A^{\dagger}&0
\end{pmatrix}$